# JQuery DropDownList change color when Selected in Asp.Net Repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a repeater in an Asp.Net solution.

I need to change the color of selected element with JQuery when the user select a specific value.

The repeater is:

```
<div class="userorderlist">
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptExtFatt" OnItemDataBound="rptExtFatt_ItemDataBound">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">
               <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="ddlModPag">
               <asp:ListItem Text="Pagata" Value="Pagata"></asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Text="In attesa di pagamento" Value="In attesa di pagamento"></asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Text="Sospesa" Value="Sospesa"></asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Text="Scaduta" Value="Scaduta"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I need to have the selected element of "ddlModPag" with a red background if value is "Scaduta" and green if is "Pagata". I know how to work with Jquery but i don't know how to capture the event for the DropDownList in the repeater.

Thanks to all

Comment: Use Jquery .change() method to caputer the dropdownlist change event

Comment: Yes but the id of a dropdownlist in a repeater is dynamic. I don't know how to call this dynamically id

Comment: use element selector or class selector  in place of id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery listener and bind it to all the DropDownLists on the page with the class name `form-control`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.form-control').change(function () {
            alert(this.value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you have other controls with that class name then it's better to give the dropdowns their own unique class.